# R: dplyr pipe conditional lead/lag using ifelse with unexpected behavior

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm trying to use a conditional `lead`/`lag` function in a dplyr pipe using ifelse but getting an error. However, using the same approach outside the pipe it seems to work. What am I missing?

```
require(dplyr)
```

Data:

```
test <- data.frame(a = c("b","b","b","b","b","b",
                         "m","m","m","m","m","m",
                         "s","s","s","s","s","s"), 
                   b = replicate(1,n=18), 
                   stringsAsFactors=F)
```

dplyr pipe:

```
test %>%
  mutate(delta = ifelse(a == "s", b + lag(b, n = 2*6),
                        ifelse(a == "m", b + lag(b, n = 1*6), 0)))

# Error: could not convert second argument to an integer. type=LANGSXP, length = 3
```

Without the pipe it works:

```
test$delta <- ifelse(test$a == "s", test$b + lag(test$b, n = 2*6),
                     ifelse(test$a == "m", test$b + lag(test$b, n = 1*6), 0))
```

I found some indication that there was an issue with dplyr `lead`/`lag` in combination with grouped data frames. But I am not grouping here.

Version info: R 3.1.1 and dplyr_0.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` fails to parse the expression. One solution is to define the function first:

```
foo <- function(a, b)
    ifelse(a=="s",b+lag(b,n=2*6), ifelse(a=="m",b+lag(b,n=1*6),0))
test %>% mutate(delta = foo(a,b))
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
test %>%
    mutate(delta = ifelse(a=="s",b+lag(b,n=12),
                          ifelse(a=="m",b+lag(b,n=6),0)))
```

works. This means that you cannot pass expressions in `lag` arguments.

Comment: If so, why `ifelse(test$a=="s",test$b+lag(test$b,n=2*6),
       ifelse(test$a=="m",test$b+lag(test$b,n=1*6),
              0))` works?

Comment: it sounds like a bug of `dplyr`.

Comment: This is related to evaluation of the expressions.  In this code all expressions are evaluated in the global environment, in the dplyr case, evaluation happens in different environment. This is probably a bug in dplyr.

Comment: [**Related issue**](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/946) (an error is generated also without the `group_by(cyl)`).